# Active state in navbar bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is my navbar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="../../static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../static/js/navbar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyFlaskApp</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-left">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="articles">Articles</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            {% if session.logged_in %}
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
              <li role="presentation"><a href="showSignUp">Register</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="showSignIn">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my navbar.js

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

I tryed the code in  http://www.bootply.com and it's working. It does exactly what I want.
But in my application it's not working when I switch the page. It still shows active on home.

This is how my files looks like:
[image]

Maybe I didn't imported right navbar.js?

Comment: Where is the bootstrap.css?

Comment: In layout.html i have "<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">" and navbar.html I included in layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from navbar.js its ok, maybe jQuery dont work locally in your project? 
Try to put it your scripts before `</body>` tag.

Comment: Yes!! You were right! I'm new in all this stuff. I must check the difference between scripts in head and the scripts in the body. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I can see how it changes as active on Articles for example, and 
 then immediately goes active for Home again..